# Python, Regex, extract grouped emails within curly brackets

Tags: python, regex, email

I'm trying to extract multiple Emails from string. I'm using this regex:

```
re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(?:\.[\w]+)+', text)
```

It works fine, but sometimes in text Email names with the same domain are grouped in curly brackets:

```
{annie,bonnie}@gmail.com
```

So my question is how properly to parse it and extract as separate emails:
`annie@gmail.com, bonnie@gmail.com`?

I've tried to modify regex to take into account brackets and comma, following with simple function, but in that case I get a lot of garbage from string.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You would use something  like `r'(?:({[^{}]*})|[\w.-]+)(@[\w.-]+(?:\.\w+)+)'` and upon finding a match, you could check if Group 1 matched, and if yes, split it with comma and build the resulting output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?:{([^{}]*)}|\b\w[\w.-]*)(@[\w.-]+\.\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gHPB71/1). *Details*:

- `(?:{([^{}]*)}|\b\w[\w.-]*)` - a non-capturing group matching:
- `{([^{}]*)}` - a `{`, then Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`
- `|` - or
- `\b\w[\w.-]*` - a word boundary (it will make matching more efficient), a word char, and then zero or more word, dot or hyphen chars
- `(@[\w.-]+\.\w+)` - Group 2: a `@`, one or more word, dot or hyphen chars, then a `.` and one or more word chars.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3BQb2J):

```py
import re
text = "Emails like {annie,bonnie}@gmail.com, annie2@gmail.com, then a bonnie2@gmail.com."
emails = []
rx_email = re.compile( r'(?:{([^{}]*)}|\b\w[\w.-]*)(@[\w.-]+\.\w+)' )
for m in rx_email.finditer(text):
    if m.group(1):
        for email in m.group(1).split(','):
            emails.append(f'{email}{m.group(2)}')
    else:
        emails.append(m.group())
print(emails)
# => ['annie@gmail.com', 'bonnie@gmail.com', 'annie2@gmail.com', 'bonnie2@gmail.com']
```

The logic is

- Get the emails with `{...}` in front of `@` while capturing the contents inside the braces into Group 1 and the `@...` into Group 2
- Check if Group 1 was matched, and if yes, split the contents with a comma and build the resulting matches by concatenating the comma-separating user names with the domain part
- If Group 1 did not match, just append the match value to the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.findall` along with a list comprehension:

```py
inp = "{annie,bonnie}@gmail.com"
parts = re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}(@\S+)\b', inp)[0]
emails = [email + parts[1] for email in parts[0].split(',')]
print(emails)
```

This prints:

```
['annie@gmail.com', 'bonnie@gmail.com']
```

Comment: `r'\{(.*?)\}(@\S+)\b'` will no longer match `annie@gmail.com`.

Comment: It's working, maybe just a little not comfortable - need to apply 2 functions: first extract all normal Emails, second - address all grouped cases.

Comment: @Oleksii Well you need a bunch of extra work for the `{...}` case, and I don't see any way around that.  If you really want to make just a single pass, then look into using a regex iterator.  You can match for either case, and then decide how to handle each one.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 'xy2@gmail.com data@gmail.com google@gmail.com {annie,bonnie}@gmail.com'
q = []
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    if '{' == j or '}' ==j :
        q.append(i)  
    
y1 = x[q[0]+1:q[1]]
a1 = y1.replace(','," ")
a1 = a1.split(" ")
z = [i+'@gmail.com' for i in a1]

x = x.replace("{",'')
y = x.replace("}",'')
z1 = " ".join(z)
z2 = y.replace(y1,z1
```